# Can I make an extremely sharp filter?

Tags: filter

I am asked to design a circuit to measure certain signal in range of about 100 kHz, while interference that may appear can be about 150 kHz. Is it even possible to split the two? What needs to be done to get a very narrow band filter, say 5% of the central frequency with at some -10dB at 120% of the frequency?

Comment: This sounds like homework, so you need to show your work and what you've figured out so far.

Comment: I don't see the need for a *narrow band* put into numbers. Frequencies 2:3 isn't intimidatingly close. What characteristics are necessary for pass-band & stop-band? (en.wikipedia on [filter requirements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_design#Typical_design_requirements)) Is digital processing an option?

Comment: Phase doesn't matter. Need to measure amplitude as accurately as possible, so the gain should be very flat in passband.

Comment: Source impedance?  Punching in your numbers, I get that a 4th order Butterworth filter can achieve that rejection:  https://markimicrowave.com/technical-resources/tools/lc-filter-design-tool/  You'll need fairly large inductors though, so using a digital filter would probably be a lot easier.

Comment: How flat in band? 5% is the desired bandwidth, so, 95 to 105kHz +/- some dB?

Comment: @TimWilliams 95khz to 105khz i would want 0.1dB

Comment: @user1850479 yes, true. however i am worried of things like megaohm resistors and capacitor tolerance. trying to simulate the effects. I hoped experienced people would know better :)

Comment: How much rejection do you need at 150kHz? Is it only at 150, or are other frequencies important too? (Would a low-pass, asymmetrical bandpass, or notch, fit your requirements?)

Comment: @TQQQ That link let's you pick the resistor values and then produces models that you can use to simulate the effect of tolerancing. I think probably there are better solutions, but it's very handy to use a quick tool to see how complex a possible solution could be and how sensitive you would be to tolerances.

Comment: @user1850479 thank you, i am checking it too.

Comment: How uncertain is the 150 kHz interference frequency? A notch filter to kill the interference might be an option. Either in place of or in addition to the the bandpass filter.

Comment: @TimWilliams honestly i don't really know. I mean, i know that the thing that generates the frequency and the other one that interferes are both a bit floating. But i really don't want to follow the frequency if i don't have to. And rejection - well, probably gain of -30dB should be enough, -20dB probably acceptable

Comment: Are you sure you really need 0.1 dB flatness?  A lot of applications can use larger amounts of deviation from flatness, so long as the deviation is known and of a 2nd order or less.

Comment: How well known are these sources? Could you get a phase reference from one?  If so, you can use a mixer to select or reject it by correlation alone; ratios of 40dB are reasonable with fairly ordinary components (unmatched diodes or analog switches), and basically the sky's the limit with fine enough tuning (see also: lock-in amplifier). Even if not directly possible, perhaps a PLL can track one signal well enough for a similar filtering effect.

Comment: @SteveSh not sure, but so it seems.

Comment: @TimWilliams the source is not well known. One though is the the signal can be detected and tracked. But then the board becomes complex enough to probably put something digital and just display spectrum by FFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a sharp filter, but the pass band requirements of 0.1 dB ripple make this a bit more difficult. I suggest using a loosely coupled filter with a 0.1 dB Chebyshev response. The particular loose coupled topology is so you can use two-opamp gyrators for the grounded inductors. I prefer gyrators over multiple feedback filters for noise performance. If you don't need low noise, a multiple feedback topology will be easier to implement.

[image]

This filter topology is discussed in "Electronic Filter Design Handbook", by Williams & Taylor, Chapter "Narrow-Band Coupled Resonators", page 5.19 (second edition). This topology works well for Q > 10.

Of course, you can create a bandpass filter in the digital domain which would be easier if you have the computational power.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, they don't want to do digital right now. Hopefully later they will agree to simply do a device with a display doing FFT and showing the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a *very* narrow bandpass is using an *active* filter. Effectively, the Q of the tuned circuit is multiplied by amplification, and, with feedback, is virtually *unlimited*.

Some examples of R-C active filters design can be fount at [Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html) and at [Electronics Hub](https://www.electronicshub.org/active-band-pass-filter/), and [Okawa-Denshi has an online *Multiple Feedback Band-pass Filter Design Tool*.](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuBakeisan.htm)